# Why is the 'Top Events' report showing strange data?

Tags: events, google-analytics, report, analytics, google-analytics-api

The top events report in analytics is showing really strange numbers and I'm not sure why. It was noticed because a bunch of the same event category/actions (with different labels and pages that they would happen on) would have the exact same amount of events occuring (ie: 8 with 83, ~15 with 62, ~75 with 21) yet these events are on pages with drastically different pageviews so they shouldn't have such similar counts for clicking the contact button)...

Also, if I make a custom flat table report and report on the same numbers they show what seems to be a much more accurate picture... Is there something odd about the numbers in 'Top Events' that I'm not understanding that would mean the numbers it's reporting are correct, or is it actually just messed up/a bug/etc?

note: also notice in the custom report it also reports on 4 different events from the same page happening throughout the year (as the email changed several times) whereas the top events report only shows 1... The single item reported in Top Events corresponds to the 3rd item in the flat table

Top Events:
[image: top events report]

Custom Flat Table:
[image: custom flat table]

Answer (score 0):

I'm under the impression that you didn't set these event triggers up, so these are spambots that are sending fake event data to your analytics. You may see some spammy referral data in your Referral reports too (unless you've done some filtering already).

Since you mentioned that the events don't correlate to pageviews, they are likely ghosts (They are just sending analytics data without actually visiting your site). You'll want to set up something like a Hostname filter to prevent ghost referrals from sending data to your property without actually visiting your server.

For reference, if they were not ghosts (and were actually going to your site), you'd need to either set up more specific Source filters in GA, or a server-side blacklist.

[Here is a good article on the motives behind spambots](http://www.wiyre.com/google-analytics-darodar-forum-spam-what-is-it/), and [here are some options for how to filter them](https://gearside.com/stop-spambots-like-semalt-buttons-website-darodar-others/).

Comment: thanks for the input..I've heard about spambots before, that's not the case here, these are real events we've set up in tag manager and they all come from our site... That also wouldn't explain why the 'top events' report shows such different (incorrect) data then a custom report with the same fields.